# Flag to generate 'deterministic' floating point operations wrt. pointer alignment with 'fast-math'?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-alignment, fast-math

The `-ffast-math` option in gcc allows the compiler to reorder floating-point operations to have a faster execution.

This may lead to slight differences between the results of these operations depending on the alignment of pointers. For instance, on x64, some optimized instructions (AVX) are faster on pointers that are 128-bits aligned so it makes sense that the compiler could be allowed to do that.

Here is an example of a simple program that shows such a behavior on a modern CPU:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


double sum(int size, double *a) {
        double r = 0.0;
        for (int k = 0;k < size; k ++) {
          r+= a[k];
        }
        return r;
}

void init(int size, double *a) {
  srand(0);
  for (int k = 0; k < size; k ++) {
          a[k] = ((double) rand()) / RAND_MAX;
  }
}


void test(int size, double *ref, double *arr) {
  init (size, ref);
  memcpy (arr, ref, sizeof *arr * size);

  printf("Alignment: ref:%d  arr:%d diff:%g\n",
    (int)((uintptr_t)ref % 32),
    (int)((uintptr_t)arr % 32),
    fabs(sum(size, arr) - sum(size, ref)));
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int size = argc <= 1 ? 100 : atoi(argv[1]); // (don't do that at home)
  double *array1 = malloc(size * sizeof *array1);
  double *array2 = malloc((size + 4) * sizeof *array2);
  printf("size = %d\n", size);
  if (array1 && array2) {
    for (int k = 0;k < 4;k ++){
      test(size, array1, array2 + k);
    }
  }
}
```

That may output when compiled with `-Ofast`:

```
$ ./test 100000
size = 100000
Alignment: ref:16  arr:16 diff:0
Alignment: ref:16  arr:24 diff:7.27596e-12
Alignment: ref:16  arr:0 diff:0
Alignment: ref:16  arr:8 diff:7.27596e-12
```

## Question

Is there a magical flag that politely ask the compiler not to generate code that is sensitive to the alignment of pointers without completely forbidding "fast-math" optimizations ?

## More Details

Here is the configuration of my gcc:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

I simply compiled the above code with nothing more than "gcc -Ofast".

By looking at the generated assembly code, it seems that the compiler is implementing the following pseudo-code:

```c
typedef struct {
    double lower;
    double upper; 
} packed_double128; 

double sum6(int size, double *a) { ... an array of size smaller than 6 and at least one in an "unrolled" fashion ... }

double sum(int size, double *a) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    } else if (size - 1 <= 5) {
        int delta;
        double tmp; 
        if (((intptr_t) a) % 16) {
           delta = 1; 
           tmp = a[0];
        } else {
            delta = 0; 
            tmp = 0.0;
        }        
        packed_double128 res = {0., 0.}; 
        double *p = a + delta; 
        assert (((intptr_t) p) % 16 == 0); // p is aligned !
        for (k = 0; k < (size - delta) / 2; k ++) {
            res.lower += *p++;
            res.upper += *p++;            
        }
        double res = res.lower + res.upper + tmp; 
        int remain = size - 2*((size - delta) / 2); 
        if (remain) 
          return res + sum6(remain, p); 
        else 
          return res; 
    } else {
        return sum6(size, a); 
    }
}
```

For instance, if a is the array {0, 1, 2,.., 10} `sum` computes:

- ((0+2+4+6+8)+(1+3+5+7+9))+10 if it a is "aligned"
- ((2+4+6+8+10)+(1+3+5+7+9))+1 if a is not "aligned"

Here is the assembly code (the comment are mine and may be wrong):

```
sum: // double sum (int size, double *a)
.LFB61:
    .cfi_startproc
    testl   %edi, %edi       // size = 0 ?
    jle .L8 ;
    movq    %rsi, %rax  ;    // rax = a
    leal    -1(%rdi), %edx ; // edx = size - 1
    shrq    $3, %rax         // rax = rax >> 3
    andl    $1, %eax         // rax = rax % 2
    // now eax contains either 1 or 0 depending the alignment, let's call this value "delta"
    cmpl    $5, %edx         // size - 1 <= 5 ?
    jbe .L9
    testl   %eax, %eax       // a % 16 = 0 ? if so, skip the next two mov (and initialize xmm2 to 0)
    je  .L10
    movsd   (%rsi), %xmm2    // xmm2 = a[0] (we put aside the first element)
    movl    $1, %ecx         // ecx = 1
.L4:
    movl    %edi, %r9d          // r9d = size
    pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1        // xmmm1 = 0
    subl    %eax, %r9d          // r9d = size - delta
    leaq    (%rsi,%rax,8), %rdx // rdx = a + eax * 8 (which is "&a[rax + delta]")
    xorl    %eax, %eax          // eax = 0
    movl    %r9d, %r8d
    shrl    %r8d                // r8d = (size - delta) / 2
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L5: // HERE IS THE "real loop"
    addl    $1, %eax            // eax ++
    addpd   (%rdx), %xmm1       // xmm1 += *rdx (thas's adding 2 doubles into xmm1)
    addq    $16, %rdx           // rdx += 2 * sizeof(double)
    cmpl    %r8d, %eax          // eax < (size - delta) / 2 ?
    jb  .L5
    // Here xmm1 contains two halves of our sum:
    // one double is the sum of odds elements and the other the sums of even elements
    movdqa  %xmm1, %xmm0        // xmm0 = xmm1
    movl    %r9d, %edx          // edx = size - delta
    andl    $-2, %edx           // edx = r9d - (r9d % 2)
    psrldq  $8, %xmm0           // xmm0[0] = xmm0[1]; xmm0[1] = 0.0;
    addpd   %xmm0, %xmm1        // xmm1 += xmm0 (which now means that xmm1[0] contains the final result \o/ )
    cmpl    %edx, %r9d          // r9d = r9d - (r9d % 2) ? eg. r9d % 2 = 0 ?
    leal    (%rdx,%rcx), %eax   // eax = rdx + 1
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    addsd   %xmm2, %xmm0        // xmm0 = xmm1 + xmm2[0] Here we add the skipped element in case of misalignment
    je  .L13
.L3: // BORING UNROLLED LOOP FOR SMALL ARRAYS (size <= 6)
    movslq  %eax, %rdx
    addsd   (%rsi,%rdx,8), %xmm0
    leal    1(%rax), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %edi
    jle .L1
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    addsd   (%rsi,%rdx,8), %xmm0
    test    2(%rax), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %edi
    jle .L1
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    addsd   (%rsi,%rdx,8), %xmm0
    leal    3(%rax), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %edi
    jle .L1
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    addsd   (%rsi,%rdx,8), %xmm0
    leal    4(%rax), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, %edi
    jle .L1
    addl    $5, %eax
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    cmpl    %eax, %edi
    addsd   (%rsi,%rdx,8), %xmm0
    jle .L1
    cltq
    addsd   (%rsi,%rax,8), %xmm0
    ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L8:
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
.L1:
    rep ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L10:
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    pxor    %xmm2, %xmm2
    jmp .L4
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L13:
    rep ret
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L9:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    jmp .L3
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: `double *array2 = malloc(size * sizeof *array2 + 4);` is a mistake. That adds four **bytes** to the requested size, but `for (int k = 0;k < 4;k ++){ test(size, array1, array2 + k); }` requires three additional **elements**. Consequently, your program overruns the allocated space and has undefined behavior, so it does not demonstrate there is any difference in computation due to alignment—the difference may be due to the buffer overrun. Depending on how the memory returned by `malloc` happens to be positioned, the `memcpy (arr, ref, sizeof *arr * size);` may alter `ref`, for example.

Comment: `(size + 4) * sizeof *array2` makes more sense to allocate.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a typo in my example. 
But it does not change the behavior (I'll edit the question): the change in the sum is not explained by this mistake.

Comment: To be clear: @EricPostpischil rightfully pointed a mistake in my example that has been fixed; but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Marc: If you want to be clear, you need to assert that the output of the program with the correction is the same as before.

Comment: You are right, it is :). Thanks !

Comment: I cannot reproduce the outcome. All diffs are zero for me. I only used `-Ofast -std=c99 -lm` as cmline flags, do you have other flags? [If you look at the disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/hM8pHg) you'll see that gcc is vectorizing the loop with `movupd`. Can you post your disassembly? I don't think alignment counts unless your version of gcc generates a runtime dispatcher. Alignment would impact performance (on cache splits and at instructions level) but not accuracy.

Comment: @MargaretBloom : have you tried it with a big enough array (eg. 100000) ?
Anyway, I posted the generated assembly (note that I removed the call to "exp" to simplify, the diff is observable with or without the exp (but it may require that your system provide a "vectorized" implementation of exp)).

Comment: @Marc Exactly, without a vectorised `exp` gcc wasn't vectoring the code. Without `exp` I can reproduce your outcome and the code generated is very similar. While most SSE instructions can handle unaligned operands just fine, cache lines split (on loads) are slower on old uarchs. And when processing 16B (128b) per iteration, if starting unaligned, there's a split every 4 iterations. That's why GCC skip the first element if needed (note it assumes doubles are aligned on 8B). Using `-march` will probably get rid of the alignment check but that's an hack.